# Change the virtual path for static content

Tags: servicestack, static-content

I'm working on a project that is a self hosted service stack site hosting 2 separate "Plugins". I am trying to set it up so that I can serve up my static content files from the plugin directories so that I can edit them on the fly while debugging and not require a rebuild to copy the chages to the bin directory.

I already have this working for the my razor files by adding this:

```
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat { VirtualPathProvider = new FileSystemVirtualPathProvider(this, "../../../Project1") });
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat { VirtualPathProvider = new FileSystemVirtualPathProvider(this, "../../../Project2") });
```

I cant seem to figure out how to do the same for my static content files. It seems that I could fix one project at a time by adding `EndpointHostConfig.Instance.WebHostPhysicalPath = "../../../ProjectName";` but not both at the same time? Is there a way to set the virtual path provider for all files served and not just razor files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack has not switched over to use the `VirtualPathProvider` to handle static files contents.

Determining a request for a static file happens at the start of the ASP.NET request pipeline (i.e. before it reaches ServiceStack's IHttpHandler's) at a point where resolving a `VirtualPathProvider` is not ideal (i.e coupling).

We're currently investigating the consequences of using a virtual path since it invalidates the physical path that's expected by the host web server.

#### Overriding ServiceStack's default behaviour

The [first 2 hooks in ServiceStack's Order of operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) allow you to inject custom logic and handle static file requests to override ServiceStack's default behavior, both are configurable in `AppHost.Configure()` and in both cases you can return an `IHttpHandler` if you want to hi-jack the request:

1) Config.RawHttpHandlers:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { 
    RawHttpHandlers = { (httpReq) => ... },
});
```

2) IAppHost.CatchAllHandlers:

```
this.CatchAllHandlers.Add((httpMethod, pathInfo, filePath) => ...);
```