# Structure for combined ServiceStack services and website

Tags: architecture, servicestack, servicestack-razor

With Razor support, ServiceStack is a complete framework for creating both REST-services and websites.

When making **both a website and services, how would you structure this?** Not unnecessarily complex, but with an *option to scale* when the codebase gets large (and to make it easier for multiple developers to keep from working on the same files).

I've found bits and pieces, but would like **a complete recipe/best practice**.

Bits and pieces I have found:

- [Plugins](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services#encapsulating-services-inside-plugins), but can a whole website with static content and razor be contained within?
- Move `.cshtml` files to another project, then include with the [VirtualPathProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964764/change-the-virtual-path-for-static-content) parameter to the `RazorFeature` plug-in (combine multiple `FileSystemVirtualPathProvider` in a `MultiVirtualPathProvider`). Don't think static content is included.
- Razor files can also be [included as compiled views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398431/servicestack-razor-files-in-separate-project/30445859#30445859)
- Separate projects/solutions: the [website calls the services via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414186/standalone-servicestack-service-for-web-native-mobile-app?rq=1) of the service-project (much like a single-page app would do with AJAX). Feels ineffective though, to involve HTTP when it's residing on the same host.
- Single-page app calling the web-services and building content with JS instead of Razor (has a steep learning curve and no intellisense?). The SPA could be in a separate project, as all communication with the services are via WS HTTP.

*PS: I know this has similarities with [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398431/servicestack-razor-files-in-separate-project), hope it's okay though*.

Comment: I think the question is perhaps in too broad in scope and too specific for the implementation which is why it remains unanswered. 
There are a number of examples to be found @ https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Single-page-apps which might be of help and provide, if not your exact recipe, then at least the general concepts.

Comment: I agree it's hard to answer. But it also seems others are having the same question. The examples are great, but all for small projects, which is why I asked in the first place. 

Part of what attracted me to SS vs MS's free offerings, was that some intelligent people had put together a stack, which I could build and learn from. That's why the tutorials, examples and articles are almost as important as the framework itself. 

SPA is a good match for SS, but is not the solution for every website. However that's what I myself found to be the solution to a combined services and webpages site.